# Tomcat 8 Failed creating Java jli.dll

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

My application worked over Tomcat8, but
today tomcat8 don't start.
The following error appears on the server

```
    [2019-02-20 00:43:08] [info]  [ 2112] Commons Daemon procrun (1.1.0.0 64-bit) started
    [2019-02-20 00:43:09] [info]  [ 2112] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
    [2019-02-20 00:43:09] [info]  [ 2380] Starting service...
    [2019-02-20 00:43:09] [error] [ 2380] The specified procedure could not be found.
    [2019-02-20 00:43:10] [error] [ 2380] Failed creating Java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\jli.dll
    [2019-02-20 00:43:10] [error] [ 2380] Class does not exist.
    [2019-02-20 00:43:10] [error] [ 2380] ServiceStart returned 1
    [2019-02-20 00:43:10] [error] [ 2380] Class does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat Service can be created with **jvm.dll** not with (jli.dll). Please check whether the tomcat service is created with right dll. Also do you have jli.dll in your JDK\bin directory? If not re-install or copy it from other system. If any virus scanner is running in your machine, it may delete the dll file. Please verify the required dll files are available in your installation.